# Order Maven Versions Plugin to use specific repositories only

Tags: maven, versioning, nexus

Maybe this is too granular, but I would like to order [Maven Versions Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) to use only specific repositories to check for (new versions). The reason for this is: I want the plugin to check only internal company dependencies (from local Nexus) and there is no reason why we should check external repos. (Takes some times and it's also a security issue in a way). I have the following setup in the parent ("config") POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>com.mycompany.*:*</include>
        </includes>
        <serverId>automation-nexus</serverId>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The config above works fine in terms of not updating "external" dependencies, but "com.mycompany" artifacts are still queried from all other repositories. As you can see, I tried to use `<serverId>`, but that was just a guess, and it doesn't seem to do any "filtering" (I guess this is just a way to use specific credentials)

Any ideas if this is feasible or not?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your settings.xml instead and not the versions plugin configuration like this:

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

By using the above settings you will limit the access to the above group and furthermore you can search within the repository group instead of any external repository.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but in our current environment we have 3 repositories: our internal main nexus (mirroring Maven repos), our internal release nexus (containing only our own libraries), and Atlassian repo. Obviously I would like to check only the second repository. How should I modify settings.xml to achieve this?

Comment: You shouldn't modify the settings. You have to change the configuration in Nexus. That's the idea behind that to do changes in ordering of repository only in repository manager and not the client side (settings.xml).

Comment: Our Nexus instance(s) won't work with HTTPS due to firewall (security) limitations (and AFAIK, Atlassion's repo is behind HTTPS), so we have to use multiple profiles/repositories. So my goal is not achievable with our system topology?